# How do I use BETWEEN and AND in Access SQL to filter on a date range?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access, between

I am using an Access database that has table `Visits` with field `VisitDate` whose values are stored as a strings (e.g. `01/21/2020`). I need to extract all records using `VisitDate` fields values between `1/20/2020` and `1/26/2020`. The best I can do, after working on this problem for that last five days is...

```vb
dim WHEREclause as string = " WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN " & ccc & " AND " & ddd
```

where `ccc` is `"01/20/2020"` and `ddd` is `"01/26/2020"`. This gives me the correct records for year 2020, but it also return records from the same time period in 2019. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Store dates as Date/Time, not strings (if you want it to work, that is).

Comment: What a complete disaster this is. Dates should never be stored as text if it can possibly be avoided but, if they are, they should be stored in a format where "alphabetical" order will match chronological order, which usually means "yyyy-MM-dd". As it stands, you cannot use `BETWEEN` on this data because that will create an alphabetical partition, not a chronological partition. What you may be able to do is convert the column value to an actual date, e.g. `WHERE CDATE(VisitDate) BETWEEN`. I'm not sure of the correct syntax but you can check that.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the comments by @LarsTech and @jmcilhinney. Use parameters and Convert the string field to a real date.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode(ccc As String, ddd As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
    cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From Visits WHERE CDate(VisitDate) BETWEEN @FirstDate AND @SecondDate;")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(ccc)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("SecondDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(ddd)
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Please be aware that with Access, the names of the Parameters do not matter. It is the order that the parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order that the parameters are added to the Parameters collection. I use descriptive names for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with #

```
dim WHEREclause as string = " WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN #" & ccc & "# AND #" & ddd & "#"
```

nb: beware of concatenating string, it facilitates sql injections

Comment: I haven't tested but I suspect that that will cause a data type mismatch, given that `VisitDate` is not a date. Maybe an implicit conversion will be performed but I'm not sure that I'd rely on that.